# Как объединить результаты нескольких вызовов TDirectory.GetFiles в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Как прописать, что бы программа обрабатывала разные расширения файлов при выборе двух **CheckBox**.

На форме два checkBox. Делаю по отдельности, то есть:

```
if CheckBox1.Checked then
  afList := TDirectory.GetFiles(memo_Folders.Lines[i], '*.ini', RL);
if CheckBox2.Checked then
  afList := TDirectory.GetFiles(memo_Folders.Lines[i], '*.txt', RL);
```

Все работает. Если выбираю два чекбокса, то получаю только `.txt`.

Что нужно прописать, что бы при отметке CheckBox1 и CheckBox2 программа обрабатывала оба типа файлов - `.ini` и `.txt`

Comment: Если делаю А, то все работает, а если Б - то ***ничего не работает***. Это очень неинформативное описание. Компьютер же не выключается стирая все данные с диска? Старайтесь все же описывать ***что именно в работе не совпадает с ожидаемым результатом***.

Answer (score 6):

`TDirectory.GetFiles` возвращает массив имен. Следовательно, все, что нужно сделать - это объединить два массива

```
// Изначально массив пустой
SetLength(afList, 0);
if CheckBox1.Checked then
  afList := Concat(afList, TDirectory.GetFiles(memo_Folders.Lines[i], '*.ini', RL));
if CheckBox2.Checked then
  afList := Concat(afList, TDirectory.GetFiles(memo_Folders.Lines[i], '*.txt', RL));
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло.

Comment: @Татьяна Если помогло, то отметьте ответ как верный

Comment: Пока что нет репутации что бы поставить плюс.

Comment: @Татьяна "Голосовать за" и "Отметить ответ как верный" это две разных привилегии. Для "голосовать за" нужно 15 репутации. Для "отметить как верный" - 1